# Does function overloading work in ruby?

Tags: ruby, overloading

Can you define multiple versions of the same function in ruby like is possible in C?

E.g.

```
def meth(name, string, thing)
```

and

```
def meth(array_of_things)
```

Will ruby call the right method depending on the variables passed into it?

If not how can I accomplish this.

Comment: That isn't actually possible in C; you might be thinking of C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is done all over the place in Ruby. There are several ways to do it.

By using duck typing, you can do:

```
def meth arg1, arg2 = nil, arg3 = nil
  if arg1.respond_to?(:some_method) then ...
  else ...
  end
end
```

By the number of arguments, you can do:

```
def meth *args
  case args.length
  when 3 then ...
  when 1 then ...
  end
end
```

By the class of the first element, you can do:

```
def meth *args
  case args.first
  when String then ...
  when Symbol then ...
  end
end
```

Using optional arguments, you can do:

```
def meth arg1, arg2 = nil, arg3 = nil
  if arg2 then ...
  else ...
  end
end
```

---

My favorite application of this practice is when I have pairs of setter and getter methods. When no argument is given, the method works as a getter; when an argument is given, it works as a setter. For example, if there is `obj` on which a getter/setter method `foo` is defined, I can use it in either way:

```
obj.foo               # as a getter
obj.foo(some_value)   # as a setter
```

I learned this from jQuery API.

Comment: Interesting, though I would be extremely careful of conflating your getters and setters in that way. Those two behaviors are wildly different (query vs command) and I would expect them to be differentiated in a typical API.

Comment: Yes, the bit about the setters is really odd. Why wouldn't you use `obj.foo = some_value`?

Comment: @sepp2k In the middle of a chain, it is more convenient to have something that returns the receiver, just as with jQuery setters. In addition, I am mentioning some custom setters that can possibly do more than just assigning a value to an instance variable.

Answer (score 4):

No, Ruby does not support method overloading. If you define a method with the same name twice, the second definition simply replaces the first.

---

To achieve the same effect, you'd take a variable number of arguments and then check how many there are at runtime.

Depending on the context that might be overkill though. Often the best idea is simply to give your two methods different names.